# Curl not working on brand new install of Big Sur

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to run `curl` in the command line on a relatively new install of MacOS 11.2.3, and I'm getting the following error:

```
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

If anyone knows how to resolve this it would be grand